# Surjective differentiable map is an isometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, isometry

This is exercise 1.2 in Svetlana Katok's Fuchsian Groups.

$\mathbb{H}$ is the upper half plane (with the hyperbolic metric), and $f:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow\mathbb{H}$ is a surjective $C^1$ map. I want to show $f$ is an isometry (in terms of the hyperbolic metric) if and only if it preserves the Riemannian norm on the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{H}$.

One direction I can do (isometry implies norm-preserving), but the other direction is giving me trouble. I've shown that if $f$ is norm-preserving, then it also preserves the length of curves, so that 
$$ d(f(z),f(w))\le d(z,w) $$

But I can't seem to show there's equality here. In particular, I can't show $f$ is injective. Am I missing something special about the upper half plane?

Comment: Have you used the fact that $f$ must map a geodesic to a geodesic?

Comment: @TedShifrin: yes that would solve it! How can I show that though? I don't even know that $f^{-1}$ exists yet.

Comment: This follows from the fact that $f$ pulls back the Riemannian metric to itself. Geodesics are invariants of the metric.

Comment: @TedShifrin: ok, thank you, that is more advanced than I was expecting. I was thinking of geodesics as being the shortest curves between two points, but I guess you have to use the Riemannian definition (I'm not really familiar here) to solve this problem.

Comment: Yup, I would definitely use the Riemannian definition, myself.

Comment: @TedShifrin: would you mind posting a solution here? I am not confident enough in what I've quickly learned by googling about detecting geodesics. I fell down a rabbit hole about covariant derivatives, and I'm not sure how to reconcile what I've read online with what is contained in Katok's book. Thanks!

Comment: I can't write out a week's lectures in differential geometry here, sorry. There's just too much background and I have no idea what's in or assumed by Katok's book. You are welcome to download my undergraduate differential geometry text, freely available at the link in my profile.

Answer (score 1):

I think this works, based on comments by @TedShifrin.

We can characterize the geodesics as those curves $\gamma$ with $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}_t}\dot{\gamma}_t\equiv0$. Since $f$ preserves the Riemannian norm, it preserves the Riemannian metric (via the parallelogram rule), and so it preserves the covariant derivative.  That is,
$$ \nabla_{df(\dot{\gamma}_t)}df(\dot{\gamma}_t)\equiv0 $$
So $f\circ\gamma$ is a geodesic.

I still don't understand *why* $f$ preserves the covariant derivative, but it seems to be true, and I've seen some messy formulas involving the Riemannian metric, claiming to prove it. Conceptually, I'm still unclear though.